# get virtualenv variables in settings file with wsgi

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I've Django application using enviroment variables (security reasons) in my `settings.py` file:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

`SECRET_KEY` variable is set in my `<virtualenv_path>/bin/postactivate`:

```
export SECRET_KEY='trololo'
```

I've had deployed application with apache, so I've used `wsgi.py` file activating virtualenv:

```
activate_env=os.path.expanduser(envP + "/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))
```

Unfortuanately `Apache` crashes with following error:

> KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'

What's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: active the environment(`source bin/activate`) and run python(`python manage.py shell`) and run these commands `import os`,`print os.environ['SECRET_KEY']`. then will you please comment the result here.

Comment: @suhail `source bin/activate` don't give any results because I've stored `export` command in `postactivate` file, therefore after `source/bin/postactivate` or `workon <myVE>` works both `print os.environ['SECRET_KEY']` and `echo $SECRET_KEY`

Comment: I usually create a seperate settings file: `settings_local.py` or `settings_server.py` file and put the `SECRET_KEY = 'trololo'` in it. also add it in `.gitignore`(so git won't track it).  and import it in `settings.py` based on some condition ie :`if localhost:from settings_local import * else: from settings_server import *`

Comment: @suhail yes, I have several settings files too. I know that untracked file with secret values might be good idea, but there must be way to do it via virtualenv variables ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `postactivate` file is a hook called when you use the `workon` command in bash. In your case, you call the python script `activate_this.py`.

I manage my settings the same way but I have a `postactivate_this.py` file in order to set my environment variables as in my `postactivate` file :

```
from os import environ

environ["DJANGO_SECRET_KEY"] = "..."
# etc.
```

Then in your `wsgi.py` file you can write :

```
activate_env = os.path.expanduser(envP + '/bin/activate_this.py')
postactivate_env = os.path.expanduser(envP + '/bin/postactivate_this.py')

execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))
execfile(postactivate_env, dict(__file__=postactivate_env))
```

You don't need a separate settings file.